# A way to put a unique ID on a node based on the taxonomy it has?

Tags: 7

I've been tasked with building a system that assigns job numbers categorized by client. Each job number is made up of a 3 letter abbreviation of the client, the current year, and a numerical number, starting from 0 and counting up for each job created.

For example a job # would look like this: ABC1400001

The 2nd job number under client ABC would be ABC1400002 etc etc

ABC = the abbreviated client name
14 = the current year
00001 = the first job created under client ABC

I'm trying to figure out a way to do something like this with drupal where each node would be a job and each client would be a taxonomy term. Grabbing the "ABC" is easy as it could just be the taxonomy term. 14 is easy as it would just be the year. The part that is tripping me up is how to get that numerical value of 00001, 00002, 00003 etc. Then lets say I had another client named DEF the first job under that client would need to start at 00001 as well. So its not as easy as just appending a node ID on to it unfortunately.

Any ideas on how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

This looks very possible with the [Serial Field](https://drupal.org/project/serial) module in combination with [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) and [Token](http://drupal.org/project/token) modules

Serial Field module page reads:

> This module provides an auto-increment (serial) field.
>
> Unlike Drupal's built-in auto-increment node ID, which is global and
>   shared by nodes belonging to all content types, serial fields are
>   managed per content type (D6) / entity (D7). For example, the serial
>   field of an Invoice instance will generate a unique sequential number
>   (starting at 1, then 2, etc.) exclusively for Invoice instances.
>
> The allocation of serial numbers by this module is atomic. In other
>   words, the serial values are unique even when multiple instances of
>   the same content type / entity are created simultaneously.